# TwitterKit iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitterkit

I have implemented TwitterKit in application to use with Twitter login. 
My question is:
Is there anyway to override twitter settings while app is running? I need to change twitter app if user changes some settings in app. If I call again

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey(twitterConsumerKey, consumerSecret: twitterConsumerSecret)
            Fabric.with([Twitter.self])
```

Twitter still uses "old credentials". 
Is there anyway to override them?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. The key and secret is set on the original init. Initializations after the first would be ignored, can you share a bit more about what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hi, Mike, thank you for your response. I have an app with three news sources which user can change. Each country has its own twitter app which I use to login. When user changes source, I need to change twitter app settings, so user can authorize twitter app connected to that account. Also, these apps have different link, terms of conditions, description, so I cannot use one app, I need to use three.

Comment: Thanks @Nemanja - if there are different sets of terms, have you thought about using Collections instead to achieve this and displaying the terms before displaying that collection - https://docs.fabric.io/apple/twitter/show-timelines.html#collection-timeline

Comment: @MikeBonnell maybe I explained wrong. Apps on apps.twitter.com have only one description and one name and the requirement is to show different descriptions based on country user picked in app. I think it should be possible to change consumerKey and consumerSecret while app is running. Something like TwitterSettings().sharedInstance().setConsumerKey(). It seems to me like ok feature to have and not to restrict users to must use one twitter app in one application.

Comment: Ahh, I see, yes I misunderstood. While I do understand your use case for this, currently it's not possible. I'll let the team know you'd like to see it added in though.

Comment: @MikeBonnell thank you for your help.